# Adding ranges under PrintOptions and determining it in a variable

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am able to add one range but was unable to add multiple ranges and determine it in a variable:

```
Set PR = ActivePresentation.PrintOptions.Ranges.Add(1, 1)
```

Is it possible to add more ranges to the above?

I tried the following which worked but I was not able to set it to equal `PR`

```
With ActivePresentation
    With .PrintOptions
    .RangeType = ppPrintSlideRange
            With .Ranges
            .ClearAll
            .Add 1, 1
            .Add 3, 3
            End With
    End With
    .PrintOut
End With
```

Is it possible to determine the above range under a variable?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ActivePresentation.PrintOptions.Ranges.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.printranges.add) adds one range and it returns a [`PrintRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.printrange) object. It can't hold multiple ranges because it represents a single range. If you have multiple ranges, then you have multiple `PrintRange` objects thus you can access them and use [`PrintRanges`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.printranges) collection.

> ## [PrintRanges object (PowerPoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.printranges)
>
> A collection of all the [PrintRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.printrange) objects in the specified
>   presentation. Each **PrintRange** object represents a range of
>   consecutive slides or pages to be printed.
>
> Example Use the [Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.printoptions.ranges) property to return the **PrintRanges**
>   collection.

So, when you add multiple ranges:

```vb
With ActivePresentation
    With .PrintOptions
        .RangeType = ppPrintSlideRange
        With .Ranges
            .ClearAll
            .Add 1, 1
            .Add 3, 3
        End With
    End With
End With
```

You then have all those ranges to the [`ActivePresentation.PrintOptions.Ranges`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.printranges) collection.

```vb
For Each Range In ActivePresentation.PrintOptions.Ranges
    Debug.Print TypeName(Range)
Next Range
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to [`ExportAsFixedFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.exportasfixedformat) to export specific slides, than you can select which slides you want to export and use `ppPrintSelection` for `RangeType` parameter:

```vb
' Select slides 1 and 3
ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(1, 3)).Select

' Export PDF with selected slides
ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Path:=savePath, _
    FixedFormatType:=ppFixedFormatTypePDF, _
    RangeType:=ppPrintSelection
```

Comment: How do I mention the above in `ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat`. I was able to use `PR` earlier. What do I do in this case?

Comment: @KusaShaha you can select the slides you want to export and then use `ppPrintSelection` for `RangeType`. Check my updated answer.